# Adding a parameter to the url in a Yii AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii, yii1.x

I have a `CHTML:ajax` function that does some AJAX stuff on a select dropdown - I simply want to do something which says..

"on change, grab the selected value & pass that as param `childID` in the URL"

This should then display the following in the `url` section of the

```
CHTML::ajax function:-
 'url' => 'isAjax=1&childID=5134156'
```

I've tried to append the variable selected onto the url but it doesn't work - can anyone see what I'm doing wrong

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#child-form select[name="Child[user_id]"]').bind('change', function(e){
  var selected = this.value;
  console.log('selected : '+selected ); // outputs an ID to the console.

   <?php echo CHtml::ajax(array(
                  'url' => '?isAjax=1&childID='+selected,
                  'type' => 'post',
                  'update' => '#parents-sidebar',
       // rest of the ajax function (quite long...)
```

Comment: Try like this: `'url' => '"?isAjax=1&childID=" + selected'`, instead of `'url' => '?isAjax=1&childID='+selected,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't take a value extracted from the dom using javascript and inject it directly into PHP code.

From the PHP.net documentation:

> Since Javascript is (usually) a client-side technology, and PHP is
>   (usually) a server-side technology, and since HTTP is a "stateless"
>   protocol, the two languages cannot directly share variables.

`CHtml::ajax()` is primarily a shortcut for generating javascript code.  So the easy solution would just be to write your javascript manually.  That will allow you to use your `selected` variable.

Note:
You might try Taron Saribekyan's solution, posted in the comments.  The idea is that the javascript expression ('...+selected') will be printed by PHP as a string, and thus be evaluated by javascript.  In theory, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

That is obvious. You have defined a `javascript` variable and you are using it in your php code! Everything inside `<?php ?>` block, will interpret on the server and before javascript. So, I think you should use normal jquery ajax method in your case. Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   "url": <?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/controller/action' ?>'?isAjax=1&childID='+selected,
    'type' => 'post',
     ...
})
```